# Representation of Three Dimensional Sovable Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I got stuck when reading Apendix II of *G-Induced Flows* by L. Auslander and L. Green and hopefully someone could help me out. The article can be found at https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373046 and let me describe the setting of my problem.

Let $S_2$ a three dimensional sovable Lie group whose Lie algebra has a basis $\{X,Y,Z\}$ with relations $[X,Z] = \sigma Y + Z, [X,Y] = Y - \sigma Z, [Y,Z]=0$, where $\sigma$ is a nonzero real number. The author then represents $S_2$ by a pair $(t,w)$, $t$ real, $w$ complex with the product relation
$$(t,w)(t',w') = (t+t',w + e^{(1-i\sigma)t}w' )$$

I wonder how this representation of $S_2$ is obtained. Are three dimensional solvable Lie group actually classifiable so that the author just identify $S_2$ by its Lie algebra and that the representation above is another well-known model for this Lie group?  Or is this representation derived purely from the Lie algebra structure of $S_2$?

Any comment is highly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, the $3$-dimensional (simply-connected, connected) solvable Lie groups have been classified, namely by their  Lie algebra. The derivative $d\rho$ of a Lie group representation $\rho$ is a Lie algebra representation of the corresponding Lie algebra.